# Putting helpText between textInput title and box in R shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have an R shiny app. In my UI.R

```
textInput("axis_order", "Enter the order to display groups (comma-separated):", placeholder = "e.g., untreated,treated"),
helpText("Do NOT use spaces."),
```

Which appears as:

Enter the order to display groups (comma-separated):

TEXTBOX

Do not use spaces.

Whereas I want it to look like

Enter the order to display groups (comma-separated):

Do not use spaces.

TEXTBOX

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```r
  textInput(
    "axis_order", 
    tagList(
      tags$label("Enter the order to display groups (comma-separated):"),
      helpText("Do not use spaces")
    )
  )
```